# Down voting who copied your comment as an answer

Tags: discussion, answers

When I was checking the First-Posts queue, I ended up on a question in which the user made a simple mistake with his code, I wasn't sure what he is doing so I pointed out to his mistake in a comment
After a while, a user have posted an answer which point out to the same thing I was mentioning in the comment, the two differences between his answer and my comment were, two words "One Solution" and the code modification which was very obvious "just two parentheses"
I have down-voted his answer and commented: "I've just said that same thing in the comment" after the OP commented "Thanks" to both of us

Now, my question is, Is down-voting his question against the community rules?
Should we down vote this kind of answers or this is wrong thing to do?

Comment: OK, I can delete this question if it's not `answerable` question in `Meta`. So I need an explanation for the down vote?

Comment: [Here's the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49310960/having-trouble-passing-back-values-in-the-function-for-items/49311429#comment85623962_49310960) and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49311429/1835379).

Comment: Yes? And I'm asking this question to know If what I did is wrong or not, that's the whole point of this question?

Comment: Just providing the links for reference.

Comment: If you know the answer why you write the answer as comment instead of writing it as a answer?

Comment: OK, nice name :)
The answer depends on if he "printing" the content of the variable immediately  or not, I wasn't sure what he is doing, that's why I commented

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't downvote this person. But I don't see why you deleted your own answer on that question, which is clearly more thorough than the other answer. If there's one simple answer to a question, and someone already answered it poorly without much detail, that doesn't prohibit you from answering it well. You should make sure your answer adds on the other answer, though. Take for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49287784/7296893), posted after mine. It has my upvote, since it's a better answer than mine, though using the same solution.

Comment: I don't care if some user copies a comment of mine exactly.  I chose to comment instead of answer, so I have little reason to moan about what happens after.  Maybe I just could not be bothered to write a full answer, maybe I was not sure that the issue I found would cure the OP's problems, maybe I am not competent in the language used.  Whatever  - if I choose to comment rather than answer, I don't care about what happens after:)

Comment: Sometimes, an OP will comment 'That was it, Martin.  You fixed my bug and, if you post an answer, I'll accept it'.  That's nice when it happens, but I don't expect it or rely on it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You chose to post your comment as a comment. If your comment happens to be an answer to the question, anyone is well within their right to post an answer on your behalf as long as they're not flat-out stealing your comment content wholesale, which is totally not the case here.

You are still free to downvote the answer if it is not in fact a useful answer to the question — but if it wasn't useful to begin with, presumably you wouldn't have said the same thing in a comment either in the first place. So downvoting based on that logic isn't very sound.

If you're just upset that someone claimed answer dibs, well, take this as a lesson learned. Don't post answers as comments. This gets harped on on meta all the time for a reason.

In fact, since you came across this question from review, one very easy way to avoid this happening again is simply by focusing on the review. Only comment to request clarification. Don't think about answering the question — unless that question really, *really* piques your interest in which case, leave the review queue, and focus on answering the question.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. I'm just complaining about the answer as it didn't add anything new, "no new content".

Comment: @Mahmoud: Yeah I'm gonna have to disagree that it adds "no new content".

Comment: `focusing on the review` Thanks for pointing out on this too.

Comment: I have another question, why do you think this question get down-vote? I really don't understand why? I could just down-voted that answer and do nothing. But I'm asking if down-voting it is write or wrong thing in this question and I get down-vote.

Comment: @Mahmoud [Voting on meta is different](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Votes are often used to express (dis)agreement with the general premise of the Meta question. These votes won't affect your main site reputation.

Comment: I don't care about reputation "I'm not asking because I'm afraid to lose reputation". What's obviously here is that my question doesn't have any "premise", I didn't presume anything, actually, I was wondering because I do care about what is with or against the community rules and guidelines. I'm not defending my action in this question, I'm questioning it, which is very strange to get down-vote on it.

Comment: @Mahmoud see it like this: your (meta) question is at the very heart of it a simple yes or no question. The votes will reflect that. It'd be very noisy if each and everyone adding their opinion would also comment and/or answer, that's simply very unnecessary.

Comment: If I spot some problem with the code, but I'm not sure that is the root cause of the OP's problems, I often post a comment instead of an answer.  If some other user wishes to gamble, take my comment and make an answer, fine.  I/they might be right, and the answer gets upvotes, or it may be 'wrong', and get downvotes.  I someone wishes to gamble the odds when I do not. fine:)

Answer (score 5):

Your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49310960/having-trouble-passing-back-values-in-the-function-for-items/49311429#comment85623962_49310960) has *no* overlap with that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49311429/1835379), other than it pointing out the same issue.

Sure, you're allowed to vote how you want, but I think it wasn't warranted at all.